# How can I set my default shell on a Mac, e.g. to Fish?

Tags: macos, terminal, fish

I do not like to retype `fish` every time I start terminal. I want [Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_(Unix_shell)) on by default. How can I set the Fish shell as my default shell on a Mac?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

These are applicable to macOS v10.12.5 (Sierra) (16F73) and probably some other recent and upcoming versions of macOS.

1. `chsh` is not enough to change the default shell. Make sure you press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> while your terminal is open and change the 'Shells open with' option to 'Default login shell.'
2. In case of Bash, make sure that you execute `echo $BASH_VERSION` to confirm you are running the intended version of Bash. `bash --version` does not give you correct information.

Comment: This is answered in [the docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-default) now.

Comment: Update: We can now set default shell in `Preferences` of *Terminal.app*. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450005/642706) by Pankaj.

Comment: I have mentioned the keyboard shortcut for preferences.

Answer (score 300):

**1.  sudo nano /etc/shells**
[image]

**2.  add /usr/local/bin/fish to your list of shells**
[image]

**3.  chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish**

Comment: And you should to change `Shell open with: Default login shell` in settings of Terminal.app

Answer (score 115):

From Terminal:

1. Add Fish to `/etc/shells`, which will require an administrative password:

   ```
   sudo echo /usr/local/bin/fish >> /etc/shells
   ```
2. Make Fish your default shell with `chsh`:

   ```
   chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish
   ```

---

From System Preferences:

1. User and Groups → ctrl-click on Current User → Advanced Options...
2. Change Login shell to `/usr/local/bin/fish`

   [image: login shell]
3. Press OK, log out and in again

Comment: Had to make a slight tweak to step 1. - `sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/fish >> /etc/shells'`

Comment: Just another way of doing the same thing @purpletonic mentioned `echo /usr/local/bin/fish | sudo tee -a /etc/shells`

Comment: Used to do it the Terminal way, but on a recent macOS upgrade, /etc/shells got reset. Probably best to use the System Preferences way in future.

Answer (score 85):

You can use [chsh](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chsh.1.html) to change a user's shell.

Run the following code, for instance, to change your shell to Zsh

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

As described in the manpage, and by Lorin, if the shell is not known by the OS, you have to add it to its known list: `/etc/shells`.

Comment: Tried and got `chsh: /usr/local/bin/fish: non-standard shell`  Solution was to add it to /etc/shells as described by @lorin-hochstein answer below

Comment: dbright@PowerMac:~$ chsh -s /Users/dbright/sys/bin/bash
Changing shell for dbright.
Password for dbright: 
chsh: /Users/dbright/sys/bin/bash: non-standard shell
dbright@PowerMac:~$ ls -l /etc/shells
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  179 Sep 23  2007 /etc/shells

Comment: Hum, I have recently tried chsh which worked as a simple user (without the `-s` though). I'll try again soon.

Answer (score 22):

Here's another way to do it:

Assuming you installed it with [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts), which can be done by doing:

```
sudo port install fish
```

Your shell will be located in `/opt/local/bin/fish`.

You need to tell OS X that this is a valid shell. To do that, add this path to the end of the `/etc/shells` file.

Once you've done this, you can change the shell by going to *System Preferences* → *Accounts*. Click on the *Lock* to allow changes. Right-click on the account, and choose *"Advanced Options..."*. In the *"Login shell"* field, add the path to Fish.

Comment: thanks! this worked great and made fish my default terminal everywhere. just changing it in terminal like one of the other answers made terminal prompt me every time i closed a window and chsh just didn't work for me.

Comment: With `macports`, follow `port notes fish` instructions after the installation. Currently, the notes state to `sudo chpass -s /opt/local/bin/fish ${USER}`.

Answer (score 14):

- type `fish` to check if it was installed correctly, if installed correctly, type `exit`
- type `which fish`, copy the path.
- type `sudo sh -c 'echo <your-fish-path-here> >> /etc/shells'`
- restart your terminal
- type `chsh -s <your-fish-path-here>`
- restart terminal again
- it should work now.

Comment: How is this any different than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20506404/11810933), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24071174/11810933), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26321141/11810933), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56995035/11810933)?  All of these are essentially (a) add `fish` to `/etc/shells` (b) `chsh`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds None of those worked for me because my fish shell path was different, `/opt/homebrew/bin/fish`

Comment: That was covered in multiple answers as well - [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66830075/11810933) specifically for the Fish shell, but 3 others for `bash` and `zsh` also mentioned using `which` to find the right location.  With 18 other answers, it's almost impossible that the information isn't replicated several times already ;-)

Comment: works with latest iterm on m1 :) thanks

Comment: Yep, this solution also worked for me (not other ones).

Answer (score 13):

#### *Terminal.app* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Shells open with* → */bin/fish*

1. Open your terminal and press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (comma). This will open a preferences window.
2. The first tab is 'General'.
3. Find 'Shells open with' setting and choose the second option which needs complete path to the shell.
4. Paste the link to your fish command, which generally is */usr/local/bin/fish*.

See this screenshot where `zsh` is being set as default.

[image: Screenshot of entering /bin/zsh in Terminal.app preferences]

I am using [macOS v10.12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra). It also works in [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave).

Comment: At last! A solution that works for a non-sudo user!

Answer (score 12):

The only thing that worked for me was a combination of all these methods.

1. First I had to add the path to the Fish executable to the `/etc/shells` file
2. Then I ran `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`
3. Finally, I typed <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> and added `/usr/local/bin/fish` to the default path there

Only after I had done all three things did Fish start popping up as the default for new terminal windows.

Answer (score 8):

On [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave) I had to do the following (using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`) as an example):

```
brew install zsh
sudo sh -c "echo $(which zsh) >> /etc/shells"
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

Comment: Note: You can use this exact method to get the latest version of bash also. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011144/117471 I came up with nearly the exact same code on my own.

Comment: No need to install `zsh`. Already present on macOS Mojave. Bundled on Mojave, and default in Catalina.

Answer (score 8):

[Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) on [M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) Macs should use `/opt/homebrew` instead of `/usr/local`.

You can check the [Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_(Unix_shell)) location `which fish`. For me, Fish was in **`/opt/homebrew/bin/fish`** which was the location I have added to `etc/shells`.

Answer (score 7):

How to get the latest version of Bash on modern macOS (tested on [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave)).

```
brew install bash
which bash | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
chsh -s $(which bash)
```

Then you are ready to [get Vim-style tab completion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48514114/117471) which is only available on Bash >= 4 (the current version in [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) is 5.0.2):

```
# If there are multiple matches for completion, Tab should cycle through them
bind 'TAB':menu-complete

# Display a list of the matching files
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"

# Perform partial completion on the first Tab press,
# only start cycling full results on the second Tab press
bind "set menu-complete-display-prefix on"
```

Answer (score 6):

This work for me on fresh install of [Mac OS X v10.12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra):

1. Define the current user as the owner of shells

   ```sh
   sudo chown $(whoami) /etc/shells
   ```
2. Add Fish to file */etc/shells*

   ```sh
   sudo echo /usr/local/bin/fish >> /etc/shells
   ```
3. Make [Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_(Unix_shell)) your default shell with *[chsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh)*

   ```sh
   chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish
   ```
4. Redefine root as the owner of shells

   ```sh
   sudo chown root /etc/shells
   ```

Comment: never `chown` system files to your current user, instead us `echo "my change" | sudo tee -a /etc/systemfile` to have the same resut of `chown $USER /etc/systemfile && echo x > /etc/systemfile && chown root /etc/systemfile`. Using tee will guarantee that you are not changing unnecessary permissions in your system

Answer (score 4):

The `chsh` program will let you change your default shell. It will want the full path to the executable, so if your shell is Fish then it will want you to provide the output given when you type `which fish`.

You'll see a line starting with "`Shell:`". If you've never edited it, it most likely says "`Shell: /bin/bash`". Replace that `/bin/bash` path with the path to your desired shell.

Comment: the -s flag was needed for me: `$ chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`

Answer (score 4):

When in the `Terminal`, open the terminal preferences using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.

On the General Tab, `Shells open with`: change from `Default login shell` to `Command`:
and using `/bin/fish`

Comment: What do you mean by *"set the autostart command fish"*? Can you elaborate/clarify? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8974180/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This is a too old answer and could be out of date, I update it with macOS Big Sur 11.4 now.

Answer (score 4):

To change your default shell on Mac, run the following:

```
chsh -s <name-of-shell>
```

The list of shells you can choose from are:

1. /bin/bash
2. /bin/csh
3. /bin/dash
4. /bin/ksh
5. /bin/sh
6. /bin/tcsh
7. /bin/zsh

so if you want to change from to the */bin/zsh* shell, your command will look like:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

You can see all the available shells on your system by running:

```
cat /etc/shells
```

Comment: Re *"chsh -s <name-of-shell>"*: Shouldn't it be *"chsh -s* ***<full-path-to-shell>*** *"**?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`dscl`](https://ss64.com/osx/dscl.html):

```
heimdall:~ leeg$ dscl
Entering interactive mode... (type "help" for commands)
 > cd /Local/Default/Users/
/Local/Default/Users > read <<YOUR_USER>>
[...]
UserShell: /bin/bash
/Local/Default/Users >
```

Just change that value (with the write command in `dscl`).

Comment: I get this error when I run read leeg:
 <dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)

Comment: Yes. That's because leeg is _my_ username, not yours :P

Answer (score 2):

In case you are having troubles with the other ways, the following worked on [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave), but it should generally work.

```
which fish
```

Add the output path to *System Preferences* → *Users & Groups* → right click *user*, *Advanced Options*. Paste the result from `which` into filed *"Login shell:"*.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file *.zshrc* and change it to

`exec /bin/bash`

Or to whatever shell you might prefer.

Bonus: this doesn't require root access and will work on every version of OS X.

The only problem is that it doesn't read file *.bash_profile* this way; it is only read if Bash is run as an interactive login shell. You would have to include it from file *.bashrc* with something like this:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
    #local hack on osx.
    if [[ -f $HOME/.bash_profile ]]; then
      . $HOME/.bash_profile
    fi
fi
```

Also: The bash version that comes with osx is a bit dated, it is preferrable to install an up to date version of bash with `brew install bash`; in this case your .zshrc file should run the correct bash version. Currently that is

`exec /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.1.8/bin/bash`