# How can I make bash tab completion behave like vim tab completion and cycle through matching matches?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I've been meaning to find a solution for this for YEARS.

I am sooo much more productive in vim when manipulating files than bash for this reason.

If I have

```
file_12390983421
file_12391983421
file_12340983421
file_12390986421
```

In bash and type file_1->tab , it obviously lists:

```
file_12390983421 file_12391983421 file_12340983421 file_12390986421
```

And this is horrible and painful to work with.

The same sequence in vim will loop through the files one at a time.

Please someone tell me how to do this in bash, or if there is another shell that can do this, I'll switch tomorrow.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/terminal-autocomplete-cycle-through-suggestions

Comment: Put `bind TAB:menu-complete` in `.bashrc`.

Comment: <C-n> and <C-p> use menu-complete by default

Comment: @D.BenKnoble C-n and C-p do nothing for me...

Comment: @pixelearth it may be only in `vi` editing mode (`set -o vi`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I have this setting, but still not working. Bash 3.2 that came with my Mac.

Comment: @pixelearth will investigate

Comment: @pixelearth If I hit `<Esc>` (so that I'm in "normal" mode on my bash prompt), `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` cycle through history. If I am in insert mode and typing text, they act like completion (cycling through possibilities). I don't have special bindings for this: it appears to just be a feature of bash/readline (I'm on 5.0.0).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

By default `TAB` is bound to the `complete` readline command. Your desired behavior would be `menu-complete` instead. You can change your readlines settings by editing `~/.inputrc`. To rebind `TAB`, add this line:

```
TAB: menu-complete
```

For more details see the `READLINE` section in `man bash`.

Comment: This works perfectly. One thing, is there a way to get this to go backwards? In vim I use shift+tab, and if I accidentally go to far, I just go back, or if I want to start at the end of the list. Something I do all day long in vim... but doesn't seem to work with menu-complete.

Comment: menu-complete will auto replace you input, but will not display a candidate list. Is there a way to do both?

Comment: @pixelearth: There is also `menu-complete-backward`, and at least on my terminal Shift-Tab seems to send the `\e[Z` escape sequence. This gives you this .inputrc entry: `"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward`

Comment: @sth Hm. I don't seem to have menu-complete-backward: GNU Readline 6.1 Snow Leopard

Comment: It'd be really cool if you could cycle through the possibilities AND see the list of possibilities, like in vim.  It's a pain to cycle through every possible file name in a directory just to find out what's in there when completing a command.

Comment: Not sure if that is still relevant, but I had the same problem as James M. Lay and solved it by putting 

`Tab:complete
  "\e[Z":menu-complete`

in my `.inputrc`. That way, `Tab` has the original behavior and `Shift` + `Tab` lets you cycle through suggestions.

Edit: There's supposed to be a line break after `Tab:complete`. I can't properly style that here in the comments.

Comment: You may want to specify that the command to be put in `.bashrc` is `bind TAB:menu-complete`.

Comment: @Claudio What is the difference between putting that bind in `.bashrc' versus putting the line in `.inputrc` as the answer suggests?

Answer (score 74):

For bash >= 4 you might like these settings.  You can try them directly on the command-line, and put them in your `~/.bash_profile` if you like them.

```
# If there are multiple matches for completion, Tab should cycle through them
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
# And Shift-Tab should cycle backwards
bind '"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward'

# Display a list of the matching files
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"

# Perform partial (common) completion on the first Tab press, only start
# cycling full results on the second Tab press (from bash version 5)
bind "set menu-complete-display-prefix on"
```

This setup is similar to Vim's `set wildmode=longest:full:list,full`

I pulled these settings from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55203/bash-autocomplete-first-list-files-then-cycle-through-them) on the Unix & Linux site.

---

By the way, since you are here, here are some other great bindings:

```
# Cycle through history based on characters already typed on the line
bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'

# Keep Ctrl-Left and Ctrl-Right working when the above are used
bind '"\e[1;5C":forward-word'
bind '"\e[1;5D":backward-word'
```

This means if you type `ssh<Up>` it will cycle through previous lines where you ran `ssh`

If you don't like what you got, you can clear the line with <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>

I pulled these settings from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/59855/133393) on AskUbuntu.

Comment: If you are using Mac OS X then check your `bash --version`. My Mac has only bash version 3, which unfortunately means the last two binds will have no effect.

Comment: I have an answer for getting the latest `bash` (currently 5.0.2) on macOS at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011144/117471

Comment: This config needs to be in .bashrc (some other answer mentions .inputrc).

Comment: Note that turning on show-all-if-ambiguous will not allow menu-complete if it's ambiguous (which might or might not be useful), unless it's bound to some other keys. // also, to figure out the key code sent press <control+v> before the key.

Comment: @Étienne `.bashrc` seems to be good for aliases. However binds throw up an error when using rsync ("warning: line editing not enabled"). So I recommend putting these binds into `.bash_profile` instead. Even better, they can be put into `.inputrc` but they need to be suitably formatted (remove the `bind` command and the quotes).

Comment: @joeytwiddle Why do you say .inputrc is even better for these settings?

Comment: @xr280xr An assumption on my part that `.inputrc` is where they are "supposed" to go (and may reduce parsing by bash). But on investigation, I see that bindings put into `.inputrc` will be used not only by bash, but by all programs which use readline!

Answer (score 17):

On top of

```
# cycle forward
Control-k: menu-complete
# cycle backward
Control-j: menu-complete-backward
```

you may also consider adding

```
# display one column with matches
set completion-display-width 1
```

This way you would preserve the current Tab functionality and make bash display the possibilities in one column. So instead of

```
file_12340983421 file_12390983421 file_12390986421 file_12391983421
```

you would get

```
file_12340983421
file_12390983421
file_12390986421
file_12391983421
```

P.S. You can get up to date `readline` library from this [The GNU Readline Library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) website.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @sth I found what works best for me:

To keep normal bash tab completion, and then use ctl-f to cycle through when needed using menu-complete

put this in your .inputrc file:

```
"\C-f": menu-complete
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the solution provided in sth's answer has never completely worked for me. **TL;DR**: Add `set -o vi` to your `~/.bashrc`.

When using menu-complete in conjunction with vi keybindings, I have to make sure that my `~/.bashrc` has:

```
set -o vi
```

It's never been enough for my `~/.inputrc` just to have:

```
TAB: menu-complete

set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

My guess is that somehow `set editing-mode` and `set keymap` are clobbering the `TAB: ...` setting, but I haven't looked into the documentation thoroughly to figure out why this is the case.

Comment: I am getting TAB command not found. I tried setting editing mode and keymap to vi but still nothing, no bash commands are found in my inputrc on macOS

Comment: @MladenPetrovic - the first `set...` part goes in `~/.bashrc`, the second `TAB:...` part goes in `~/.inputrc`.  You'd get `TAB command not found` if you put that part in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: You probably don't need `set keymap vi` anyways : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002356/what-does-set-keymap-vi-do