# Auto complete behavior in biolinux 

Tags: linux, bash, shell, autocomplete, zsh

Using the terminal under biolinux distro I realized that when I use the tab for auto completion the possible matching options are displayed under the command line and if I keep 'tabbing' each the options is automatically entered in the command line.

example:
**I type more + TAB**

```
user@biolinux more                                                       [ 2:01PM]
admin.log     Documents/    missfont.log  Pictures/     Templates/    
Desktop/      Downloads/    Music/        Public/       Videos/
```

**then press TAB again**

```
user@biolinux more admin.log                                              [ 2:01PM]
admin.log     Documents/    missfont.log  Pictures/     Templates/    
Desktop/      Downloads/    Music/        Public/       Videos/
```

Notice that pressing TAB not only gives the next option for auto complete but also displays a list of the whole options **without** adding a jumping a new line and printing the list each time I press TAB to the shell.

Apparently the default shell in biolinux is *zsh* (echo $SHELL). Is this behaviour specific to *zsh*? Can this be mimicked on **bash**?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179642/how-can-i-make-bash-tab-completion-behave-like-vim-tab-completion

Comment: Thanks! that solves the issue of scrolling through the different options but how can I have the menu of options and now jump a new line each time I press tab?

Sorry if I am not being very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html and give zsh some love :)