# What does "set keymap vi" do?

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted vim-like navigation for my terminal, so I added:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

To my `.inputrc` file based on [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal). `editing-mode vi` adds vi navigation. What does `keymap vi` do, and why do I need it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR**

If you don't want to change/add bindings in the default keymaps, you don't need the line `keymap vi`.

What `keymap vi` does is state that any bindings listed after that point apply to that keymap (which is *exactly* the same keymap as `vi-command` and `vi-move`).

If you want to change the insertion keymap (eg to add a `Ctrl-A` binding to go the beginning of the line while you're typing), you'll need to do this below a `keymap vi-insert` line.

If you want further info on the `vi` mode and maps, skip to the heading `editing-mode vi` (the last one).

But wait! There's a fair bit of background info that may be needed though: eg, the difference between an `editing-mode` and a `keymap`.

Particularly useful is the concept of a hybrid `emacs` keymap for inserting text and while still easily getting to `vi-command` for making changes.

**What is the difference between an `editing-mode` and a `keymap`?**

There are *only* two `editing-mode`s: `emacs` (the default) and `vi`.

The [GNU Readline Library documentation](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) says:

> ```
> editing-mode
>     The editing-mode variable controls which default set of key bindings is
>     used. By default, Readline starts up in Emacs editing mode, where the
>     keystrokes are most similar to Emacs. This variable can be set to either
>     `emacs' or `vi'.
> ```

Note the difference between `editing-mode` and `keymap`: In `editing-mode vi` the two (yes there's only two, read on) keymaps are swapped in and out to emulate the different modes of the `vi` editor. *ALL* the `emacs` ones operate at the same time in `editing-mode emacs` (explained later).

So what does `editing-mode` actually do? It just sets the active keymap upon shell startup to either `emacs` or `vi-insert`.

**What are the unique keymaps?**

> ```
> Acceptable keymap names are emacs, emacs-standard, emacs-meta, emacs-ctlx,
> vi, vi-move, vi-command, and vi-insert.
>
> vi is equivalent to vi-command; emacs is equivalent to emacs-standard.
> ```

While not documented, `vi`/`vi-command` and `vi-move` keymaps are also equivalent:

```
+ravi@boxy:~$ diff <(bind -pm vi) <(bind -pm vi-move)
+ravi@boxy:~$
```

This leaves us with: `emacs`, `emacs-meta`, `emacs-ctlx`, `vi`, and `vi-insert` as unique keymaps to explain. Differentiating the keymaps is probably best done by inspecting them...

**What are the keymaps default bindings?**

To view the default keybindings for (example) emacs (the default), use:

```
INPUTRC=~/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' | grep -v '^#
```

You can replace `emacs` with any other keymap name in the example above.

There are many lines saying `self-insert` or `do-lowercase-version` which aren't very useful, so to remove them:

```
INPUTRC=~/dev/null bash -c 'bind -pm emacs' | grep -vE '^#|: (do-lowercase-version|self-insert)$' | sort
```

**What is the difference between the various `emacs` keymaps?**

TL;DR: They are different views on a single set of mappings applied to `editing-mode emacs`.

If you the output of the second command into the files called `emacs-standard`, `emacs-meta`, `emacs-ctlx`, `vi-command`, and `vi-insert` for their corresponding `keymap`s, you can find out that:

There are NO commands mapped in `emacs-meta` and `emacs-ctlx` which don't also appear in `emacs-standard`:

```
$ comm -13 <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-standard|sort) <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-ctlx|sort)
$ comm -13 <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-standard|sort) <(sed -r 's/.*: (\S+)/\1/' emacs-meta|sort)
$
```

So `emacs`/`emacs-standard` is a behaviourally functional superset of both `emacs-ctlx` and `emacs-meta` This means that:

```
keymap emacs
"\eg": glob-expand-word
"\C-x\C-r": re-read-init-file
```

Is functionally equivalent to:

```
keymap emacs-meta
"g": glob-expand-word

keymap emacs-ctlx
"\C-r": re-read-init-file
```

You might argue that the second form is easier to read.

**Inserting text: `emacs` vs `vi-insert`**

There are 28 commands in `emacs-standard` not in `vi-insert`

```
+ravi@boxy:~/lib/readline$ comm -12 vi-insert emacs-standard |wc -l
28
+ravi@boxy:~/lib/readline$
```

`emacs`/`emacs-standard` is basically a superset of `vi-insert`. So for typing text, it's best to use the `emacs-standard` keymap over `vi-insert` as long as you can [easily switch between `emacs` and `vi-command`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303637/readline-how-do-i-change-from-emacs-to-vi-command-with-a-binding).

The only additional bindings in `vi-insert` not in `emacs-standard` are:

```
+ravi@boxy:~/lib/readline$ comm -23 vi-insert emacs-standard 
"\C-d": vi-eof-maybe
"\C-n": menu-complete
"\C-p": menu-complete-backward
"\e": vi-movement-mode
```

The first 3 of these four conflict with `emacs` bindings:

```
"\C-d": delete-char
"\C-n": next-history
"\C-p": previous-history
```

which I resolved as follows:

```
set keymap emacs
"\e": "kj" # see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303631/how-can-i-setup-a-hybrid-readline-with-emacs-insert-mode-and-vi-command-mode
"\C-d": delete-char # eof-maybe: ^D does nothing if there is text on the line
"\C-n": menu-complete
"\C-p": menu-complete-backward
"\C-y": previous-history # historY
"\e\C-y": previous-history
```

### **`editing-mode vi`**

As we saw above, `vi`, `vi-command` and `vi-move` are *one and the same* keymap:

```
+ravi@boxy:~$ diff <(bind -pm vi) <(bind -pm vi-move)
+ravi@boxy:~$
```

Note that's a total of just *two* distinct maps which are associated by default with `editing-mode vi`.

When in `editing-mode vi`, the `keymap`s in use are `vi`/`vi-command`/`vi-move` and `vi-insert` (the starting keymap). Only one of these two maps is active at a time.

`editing-mode vi` does nothing more than set a default keymap when the shell starts, labelled `vi-insert`. Again, tthere is only one keymap active at a time. This `vi-insert` keymap maps most keys to `self-insert` so when you press the plastic button on your keyboard, the symbol printed on it appears on your screen.

The `vi-insert` keymap allows itself to be swapped to the text-manipulating keymap called `vi-command`/`vi`/`vi-move` by using `vi-movement-mode` command, bound to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key by default in the `vi-insert` keymap.

Actually, even the `emacs` keymap can set the `vi`-like text manipulation keymap active by using the `vi-movement-mode` command, as in the hybrid solution mentioned above.

**Or in easier language...**

By default, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to change to the `vi-command` keymap when the `vi-insert` keymap is active.

The `vi-command` keymap uses standard, single keypresses like <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> to move and interact with text, just like the `vi` editor's default or command mode. There are generally no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combinations. You can't insert text in this mode; the letter keys are mapped to editing/moving commands. For typing text, you switch to the `vi-insert` keymap (example: press <kbd>i</kbd> for "Insert").

Entering text is done using the the `vi-insert` keymap, which is active when the shell starts if you have `editing-mode vi` in your `.inputrc` file. Swap to the `vi-insert` keymap by pressing <kbd>i</kbd> for "insert" while in `vi-command` (or in numerous other ways for those initiated into `vi`).

Unless you know the `vi` editor, you'll probably find `vi-command` keys very hard to use at first, but if you get good at it, you can edit text like a long-bearded wizard.

Comment: Overwhelmed at the information, underwhelmed by the presentation. Could you summarize it with the relevant facts. or use bullets or something?

Comment: I downvoted this, because it's soo needlessly complex from my perspective. I would request that you remove or at least isolate the vi-command and vi-insert. And **no one** cares about emacs here? I mean this stuff should be a footnote.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, that's how they should be gived if possible. One shares his knowledge, even if I don't solved my issue, now I'm one step further. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

From `man readline` (my emphasis):

> The set of legal keymap names is emacs, emacs-standard, emacs-meta, emacs-ctlx, vi, vi-move, vi-command, and vi-insert.  **vi is equivalent to vi-command**

Thus, in your `inputrc` you can specify different keybinds for the different modes, so, for example, in `command` mode you could yank the last argument from the previous command with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>, but this keybind would have no effect in `insert` mode (in this simple setup anyway):

```
set editing-mode vi

set keymap vi-command
# these are for vi-command mode
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\ep": yank-last-arg

set keymap vi-insert
# these are for vi-insert mode
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
Control-l: clear-screen
```

Comment: FYI, `"\ep"` is `ESC` + `p`. and `"\e[A"` is `ESC` + `[`,  `SHIFT` + `a`.

Comment: @LETs Thanks, when I want to understand the magic string, you leave me the first hint. Then I found a further doc [ANSI escape code - CSI sequences](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ANSI_escape_code#/CSI_sequences)