# How does one set specific vim-bindings in Ipython 5.0.0

Tags: python, linux, vim, ipython, prompt-toolkit

I understand that because Ipython 5.0.0 uses a new input library (prompt_toolkit) it no longer defaults to the editor mode specified in .inputrc (*nix). This option has to be set in an Ipython profile configuration file (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38329940/2915339).

My question is: having set vi-mode in the profile configuration file, how does one specify a particular keybinding? I like to use 'jk' for escape, for instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right. `prompt_toolkit` ignores `.inputrc`. There does not seem to be a way to define custom keybindings for the `vi` mode in the IPython 5.0.0 profile configuration file.

Here's workaround I'm currently using. It's not pretty, but it works for now.

According to the [IPython docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts), you can specify Keyboard Shortcuts in a startup configuration script.

Instead of rebinding `jk` to `ESC`, I'm making a unicode "j" (`u'j'`) followed by a unicode "k" (`u'k'`) inside of `VimInsertMode()` a shortcut for a `prompt_toolkit` event that switches to navigation mode.

I created a `.ipython/profile_default/startup/keybindings.py` with the following code:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
from prompt_toolkit.enums import DEFAULT_BUFFER
from prompt_toolkit.filters import HasFocus, ViInsertMode
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding.vi_state import InputMode


ip = get_ipython()

def switch_to_navigation_mode(event):
    vi_state = event.cli.vi_state
    vi_state.reset(InputMode.NAVIGATION)

if getattr(ip, 'pt_cli'):
    registry = ip.pt_cli.application.key_bindings_registry
    registry.add_binding(u'j',u'k',
                         filter=(HasFocus(DEFAULT_BUFFER)
                                 & ViInsertMode()))(switch_to_navigation_mode)
```

[The prompt_toolkit source](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/4aa0404ad7e770763b85764fd42c8dbce94f9c62/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/bindings/vi.py) will help you implement other shortcuts as needed.

Comment: This `keybindings.py` stopped working some time between IPython 5.1.0 and 7.0.1, with error message `'TerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'pt_cli'`. See https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11426/commits/e08dc1b4dd30e8d2b607134693f226e8a22100ec#diff-d47c339db04f28c44a59c6662dbd53eaR228 for a fix.

Comment: The following link also contains the updated keybindings code: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: I should have read better: running the code in `.ipython/profile_default/startup/` is crucial here. I've tried this in `ipython_config.py` which failed miserably... So, years later: this still works in IPython 7.12.0 and there's no better alternative (I searched thoroughly, all I found is that this solution is now part of the official IPython documentation).

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work with ipdb as well?

Answer (score 8):

This is an old post but it helped me find my answer so I thought I would post how I added a couple of bindings to vi mode in ipython. I added the following code in ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-keybindings.py to bind to K and J in vi navigation mode.

```
"""Improve history access so I can skip over functions"""

from IPython import get_ipython
from prompt_toolkit.enums import DEFAULT_BUFFER
from prompt_toolkit.filters import HasFocus, ViNavigationMode
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding.bindings.named_commands import get_by_name

ip = get_ipython()
registry = ip.pt_app.key_bindings
ph = get_by_name('previous-history')
nh = get_by_name('next-history')
registry.add_binding('K',
                     filter=(HasFocus(DEFAULT_BUFFER) &
                             ViNavigationMode()))(ph)
registry.add_binding('J',
                     filter=(HasFocus(DEFAULT_BUFFER) &
                             ViNavigationMode()))(nh)
```

Comment: I have been searching and searching for exactly this keybinding. I stumbled on this when looking for the right way to setup vi editing mode and I am so thankful. Thank you @GaryBishop!