# Is there any way to replace the exists default key bindings in IPython Vi mode?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I am using IPython Vi mode, and IPython sets lots of default key mappings [here](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/4aa0404ad7e770763b85764fd42c8dbce94f9c62/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/bindings/vi.py). I did a research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443907/how-does-one-set-specific-vim-bindings-in-ipython-5-0-0) and [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts), finding that I can create new key bindings by using `KeyBindingManager`.

However, if the binding I want to create exists, then it cannot works. For example, I write some code in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/vikeys.py`:

```
from prompt_toolkit.filters.cli import ViNavigationMode, ViMode
from prompt_toolkit.filters import Always, IsReadOnly

# create `handle`
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
if getattr(ip, 'pt_cli'):
    registry = ip.pt_cli.application.key_bindings_registry
    handle = registry.add_binding

navigation_mode = ViNavigationMode() & ViMode() & Always()

@handle('t', filter=navigation_mode)
def _(event):
    """
    Go up, but if we enter a new history entry, move to the start of the
    line.
    """
    event.current_buffer.auto_up(
        count=event.arg, go_to_start_of_line_if_history_changes=True)
```

Since the `t` is mapped [here](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/4aa0404ad7e770763b85764fd42c8dbce94f9c62/prompt_toolkit/key_binding/bindings/vi.py#L1146), my binding doesn't work.

I also tried to replace the `handle` with the code below, but there was no effects:

```
# create `handle`
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding.manager import KeyBindingManager
manager = KeyBindingManager.for_prompt()
handle = manager.registry.add_binding
```

So, is there any way to replace the existing key bindings in IPython?

Answer (score 0):

Answer the question myself, to help those who meet to same problem.

After reading the source code, I find that adding `eager=True` argument to the `handle` will override the default keybindings.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/zsrkmyn/ff0e5e8dc8ec22f7a25ddfc3492d3451) is an example to replace default navigation keys for Dvorak user.