# Using Vi Keys in a Jupyter Console

Tags: vim, jupyter, vi, jupyter-irkernel, jupyter-console

I would like to know how to use vi-like key bindings in a Jupyter console -- not just with ipython, but with any kernel.

[Previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394302/how-do-i-use-vi-keys-in-ipython-under-nix#38329940) show this is possible for ipython. So, perhaps there is some flag or config file where this can be specified. Jupyter does not appear to have an equivalent to `ipython profile` and giving the same flagged variables as in ipython does not work.

Answer (score 9):

The [Jupyter console documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/jupyter-console/latest/jupyter-console.pdf) almost provides the answer. For the flag, you just need to change the variable name:

```
jupyter console --kernel=ir --ZMQTerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode=vi
```

To set this option globally, you have to add `c.ZMQTerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode='vi'` to `$HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_console_config.py`. It's necessary to prefix the `'c.'`, similar to what's created when running `ipython profile create`, which the documentation does not specify.