# Arcane syntax for BASH coloring and inputrc

Tags: linux, bash, emacs

I'm trying to map some sequences of keystrokes to commands in BASH, leveraging /etc/inputrc for the sequences. In the top answer here:

[How can I make bash tab completion behave like vim tab completion and cycle through matching matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179642/how-can-i-make-bash-tab-completion-behave-like-vim-tab-completion/7179810#7179810)

The user "sth" says that "\e[Z" is the escape sequence for Shift-Tab.

How can I look up these escape sequences? What, for example, is the sequence for Alt+S, or Ctrl+S?

I've also noticed these sequences in BASH echo coloring. Like, for example:

```
echo -e "a \e[0;31m B \e[0m k"
```

Will print a (red) B, between a white 'a' and 'k'. What is this arcana? What does "\e[0;31m" mean? (red, obviously, but why not something like "\e[red]")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find what a keystroke produces empirically run `cat` and then press the key (possibly needing to first hit `ctrl-v` and then they key).

`\e` is "escape".

The rest is terminal control sequences.

See `man terminfo`. See the output from `infocmp`. Read up about this history of terminals.

Enjoy losing the next 1 to 5 years of your life and getting very annoyed at the world and learning just how wrong everyone on the internet is about this stuff at (virtually) all times.

Comment: Here's a slightly better empirical tool: `while IFS= read -rsN1 c;do printf '%02X ' '"'"$c"; done`. Here's some Linux/xterm information: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html. Here's some more: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Comment: @rici Thanks. That printf gives different output (less directly useful for the escape sequence comparison but still very useful `printf '%q'` would probably be better than `cat` here though). What's the magic with that leading quote in the argument to printf? I know I've seen it before I just can't recall the details.

Comment: printf with a numeric format of an argument starting with a quote or double-quote outputs the character code of the second character. (It's documented: "Arguments  to  non-string  format  specifiers are treated as C constants, except that a leading plus or minus sign is allowed, and if the leading character is a single or double quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character."

Comment: @rici Ah, yes, thanks. And yes, it is in the documentation if I'd bothered to look at a recent enough copy of the man page instead of the one on the CentOS 5 and 6 machines I had ssh connections to at the time. =)