# Git bash v. 1.9.5 | Tab list appearing on one press of tab

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

First, say I am in a directory with two directories:

1. Desktop
2. Development

In the example directory, if I typed 'cd de' then pressed tab, it would do nothing because two items exist with 'de' as the first two characters of their name. Then if I hit tab twice in a row, it would display a list of all possible matches.

Now, in this version, if I do the same and press tab, it will display the possible matches with only the single tab press. This is extremely annoying especially if I am trying to checkout a file and many exist with similar names, then it displays the list and pushes up what I was looking at, so now I have to scroll back up to see what files I was trying to check out.

Is this a setting somewhere I can set or do I need to switch to a different version of git?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's not git that's bash completion (unless it *only* happens for git and not other commands/etc.). There might be a setting for that but I'm not sure offhand. You could look in the man page/etc. for it though.

Comment: If this (list on single tab if there are multiple matches, instead of waiting for second tab) happens *only* for completion after `git `, then it is Git completion issue.  If it happens always, it is `bash` completion issue, and not connected to Git at all.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/7179642/46058 help?  Note also that after the first [TAB][TAB], each subsequent [TAB] counts as second one and lists completions.

Comment: Yes, I am aware it's bash, but it's through Git's git bash implementation which is why I mention Git (a different bash emulator may behave differently or have different default settings). Anyhow, @JakubNarębski thank you! I searched all over and couldn't find a way to word the query to find a useful result in the search fields. Anyhow, it's working and I submitted an answer of what worked.

Answer (score 0):

As JakubNarębski commented, I found an answer in [How can I make bash tab completion behave like vim tab completion and cycle through matching matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7179642/46058).

I created the file ~/.inputrc and added this line:

```
TAB: menu-complete
```

And voila! It works like I imagined in my wildest dreams!