# Make iTerm2 launch with Zsh

Tags: zsh, iterm2

I've been digging through iTerm2's settings but I can't seem to find a way to make it launch Zsh instead of Bash, does anybody know the proper way to do this inside iTerm2?

I ask this because I come from Mac Terminal, and it easily lets you choose what to run at startup, but I can't seem to find something straight forward with iTerm2.

I searched Google for it, but for some reason I can only find oh-my-zsh references, nothing related to un-modded iTerm2.

I appreciate any help you can provide, thanks. :)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Change your default shell to /bin/zsh by running the `chsh -s /bin/zsh` command.

Comment: Excellent! That worked, I used `chsh -s /bin/zsh` for those wondering.

Comment: `chsh -s \`which zsh\`` is perhaps a little better

Comment: Where is the setting?

Comment: @Tushar What setting?

Comment: Forgive me for my ignorance. Running the command the way you explained works perfectly.

Comment: To make this work, I had to add `/usr/local/bin/zsh` (or wherever your binary is) to `/etc/shells` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac#26321141

Comment: Make sure `/usr/local/bin/zsh` is listed in `/etc/shells`

Comment: For me, it only worked if I run this command in the Terminal app. If I run it in iTerm, it won't work for some reason.

Comment: Brilliant in its simplicity.

Answer (score 74):

Although the change with `chsh -s $(which zsh)` worked perfectly for me, my iTerm2 wouldn't automatically open new terminals with zsh.

Instead I went to `iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Default` and in the `General` Tab set the Command to `/usr/local/bin/zsh` instead of `Login shell`.

**Update:** With the current version of iTerm (as of 2.1.1) it perfectly worked for me by changing the default shell (shown above) only.

Comment: I voted this up because the hint is nearly complete. Anyway the command has to be `login -fp [username]`. Substitute [username] with your local user. Otherwise iTerm will quit immediately after start.

Comment: @Marschal You are correct. I also did the same mistake and upvoted the above answer and my iTerm started quitting the moment I made the change.

Comment: Saved the day. I had accidentally `rm -rf /usr` and so bash was gone, I was able to get a shell to try to fix the ordeal.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS ANOTHER IMMEDIATELY! CRASH!  I restore my default profile at[~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist] by my TimeMachine. And thanks to @Marschal give the right answer.

Comment: I had to use `/bin/zsh` instead of `/usr/local/bin/bash` to avoid iterm from crashing

Answer (score 8):

The following also worked for me:

Preferences -> Profiles -> General Tab -> Command -> Choose "Custom Shell" -> write "zsh"

Restart iTerm2.

I still keep bash for Terminal as the default shell.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to above answer:
Editing my zsh profile that I created,  on General tab, in the "Send text at start:" field, I have "clear; pwd; ls; zsh;"
this leaves me with a window showing me what I want to see and lastly starting zsh.