# $READLINE_LINE and $READLINE_POINT empty

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I am wondering if OSX is missing `$READLINE_LINE` and `$READLINE_POINT` variables in scripts?  I have updated to bash 4.4 and from what I read it should be available.  The function is called using `bind -x` which should populate these variables in the function call. However, when I do so, they show as empty strings.

```
testreadline() {
    echo $READLINE_LINE
    echo $READLINE_POINT
}
bind -x '"\t": testreadline'
```

When I type some command and press the `[TAB]` key, it prints 2 empty lines.

I should also mention that this works fine on my Linux VM, so I'm suspecting that there's something different with my Mac.

=========================================================================

EDIT:

The problem was when I updated to bash 4.4, I was still pointing my terminal to the old install of bash `/bin/bash`.  homebrew installs bash to `/usr/local/bin/bash` so you will need to change your preferences/profile to point to that location.

Comment: Shadowing the built-in `test` command is extremely ill-advised.

Comment: It wasn't actually test I just named it that to make it easier to read and didn't realize it was already a thing.  Changed it, but it doesn't work regardless.

Comment: Works for me on MAC using bash 4, maybe you are picking up 3.2?

Comment: Interesting... If I do `bash -version` it says 4.4.0(1)-release, but `$BASH_VERSION` is still 3.2.57(1)-release, anyone know why?

Comment: What does it say when you enter `bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION'` (single quotes are important here)?

Comment: More than likely the logon version is still 3.2.  Try `/bin/bash --version` and `$(which bash) --version`.  All you need do is to type `bash` on the command line and try again.

Comment: You can change the shell in the terminal windows via Terminal/Preferences/"Shells open with".  This is probably preferable to changing the logon shell, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac