# No I'm not able to change my default shell to fish shell

Tags: fish

I am on Mac 10.13.6

I have read this long thread and the 10 working solutions there

[How to set my default shell on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453236/how-to-set-my-default-shell-on-mac)

but nothing works for me.

Here is what I've tried

```
brew install fish
sudo vi /etc/shells
Add line '/usr/local/bin/fish' and save the file
csh -s /usr/local/bin/fish
press ⌘ ,
Shell Open with
Command complete path '/usr/local/bin/fish'
Go to system preferences
Users and Groups
select my user
click on lock icon and enter root password
go into advanced options
change Login Shell to /usr/local/bin/fish
```

Now I reboot the machine and run terminal. and still it uses BASH.

Comment: You might need to configure 'Terminal.app' to use the default login shell (or explicitly to use fish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself. thanks to Mankarse for giving me the hint.

Here is the solution

```
Click on ⌘ ,
Click on Profiles
Click on Shell
Now uncheck the "Run Command"
```

In my case the Run Command was still pointing to bash. This is my fish was not working.

[image]