# When I start my terminal I get "login: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory [Process completed]" and i cant type anything in my terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, echo, homebrew

These are the series of commands I entered that cause the problem.

```
brew install bash
echo '/usr/local/bin/bash' | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Now when I start my terminal, I get this.

```
Last login: Sun Apr  7 14:40:48 on ttys008
login: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

I can't write to the terminal unless I got to Shell->New Command and then type in "\bin\bash"

Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Well, *does* `/usr/local/bin/bash` exist? And if so, can you run it from a manually-created shell? If yes to the former and no to the latter, then the next step is to look into *why* it's not runnable -- missing dynamically-linked libraries or the like.

Comment: That said, this is probably a better fit for one of our sister sites, such as [apple.se], [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/); it's neither asking about writing software, or about tools exclusively for the purpose of writing software.

Comment: ...anyhow, until you figure out what's wrong with your `/usr/local/bin/bash`, you can just `chsh -s /bin/bash` to switch the default back.

Comment: (BTW, I'm surprised it works when you type `\bin\bash`; it should be `/bin/bash`, with forward slashes rather than backslashes).

Comment: ...it would be helpful to actually know that the `brew install bash` *worked*. Without being shown any logs from it, the only thing we're being told is that the executable wasn't actually created, which certainly implies that it failed and whatever logs that generated were simply ignored.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55011144/8258079

Answer (score 96):

1. Go to "System Preferences" > "Users & Groups"
2. Click the "Lock" icon and authenticate
3. Right-click the your user icon and select "Advanced Options"
4. Change the value for "Login shell" to /bin/bash

Comment: I specifically use bash from Homebrew, which has a symlink at `/usr/local/bin/bash`. Should I expect any issues setting it to that rather than the system `/bin/bash`?

Comment: @Sinjai I'm also using homebrew w/ symlink, and changing my default shell via the Users & Groups settings worked for me with no issues so far

Answer (score 13):

The "System Preferences" option did not work for me cause there wasn't any "Advanced Options" within "Users & Groups" (For reference: I am running Monterey 12.2). The following worked for me:

- Open a new terminal. For now it will show `/usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory`.
- Press `Command` + `,` which should open the terminal preferences.
  [image: Terminal Preferences]

- Select the `Command (complete path)` option for the `Shells open with:` choice.
- Enter the value as `/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh` based on your preference.
- Close and reopen the terminal. You should now have a working terminal.

Answer (score 2):

##### I hope below Steps can help

**Step 1.** Once bash has been installed using `brew`

```bash
brew install bash
```

**Step2.** You can verify the path of the available bash by using the following command:

```bash
/usr/bin/which -a bash
```

You now have the default `/bin/bash` and your newly configured `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` from homebrew.

By using the following commands, you can verify the version of both

- ```bash
  /bin/bash --version
  ```

  *(probably version 3.*)*
- ```bash
  /opt/homebrew/bin/bash --version
  ```

  *(probably version 5.*)*

**Step 3.** Hence, once this has been confirmed for homebrew installation, make a softlink of it to facilitate easy access,

```bash
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash
```

**Step 4.** To make it Standard Shell, modify the file /etc/shells using the following command:

```bash
sudo vim /etc/shells
```

Add an entry at the end as `/usr/local/bin/bash`

**Step 5.** Enter the following command to create a newly configured bash shell for the current user

```bash
sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

**Step 6.** To verify, close the Terminal completely and reopen it, then execute.

- ```
  echo $SHELL
  ```

  *to verify the Current SHELL*
- ```
  echo $BASH_VERSION
  ```

  *to verify the current Bash Shell version*

**Step 7.** Done