# % sign in terminal command line rather than $ sign

Tags: macos, shell, command-prompt

I am using Terminal on MacOS. My main concern is that I’m commonly seeing command lines starting with the ‘$’ sign.
My command lines begins with a ‘%’ sign. Does this matter? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `bash` is no longer the default shell in macos.  The default shell is now `zsh` which has certain advantages, such as floating-point operators.
[You may set the Terminal default shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450005/8258079) back to `bash` if needed.  It's path is simply `/bin/bash`

Comment: Along with the those certain advantages also come certain (shall we say...) dis.. .advantages too `:)`

Comment: A particularly good reason to always use the proper shebang when saving a script.